# hump on rectified signal and inconsistency on gate signal

Tags: diodes, ac, triac, gate-driving

Following is the image of my circuit, I am working at the moment. This is not my own circuit but I am trying to understand and work on it.

[image]

Following is the signal I am getting at Gate2. What could cause one gate signal fine and another gate signal worse. The Gate 1 signal is pasted at the very end ( sorry for disorder). 
[image]

Following is the signal I am getting at B'. I do not understand why I am getting bit of noise in between two half waves. This is same at A' also. When I enlarge the image, I get big hump ( Smaller than AC signal). What could cause this? This is the signal immediately after rectification from diode.
[image]

Following is the signal I am getting at Gate1. 
[image]

I am getting half output from the my system. I am guessing this might be because of the turning of only one gate. Could there be any reasons why one gate can go faulty. I replaced the TRIACS and TRIAC Driver already, but did not help. 
The vertical glitch lines on each half waveforms on third image, is that because of firing angle? or will any component cause this? I guess the reason being firing angle because this vertical line moves left and right when I decrease and increase the output. 
Any help will be highly appreciated.

so this is the rest of the picture. I hope I have included everything.
[image]

Comment: Your schematic is missing the AC supply and it's voltage, the load and, very important, where the scope probe **and probe ground lead** are connected in each of your scope measurements.

Comment: Without additional information this question is impossible to answer. Sorry, voting to close.

Comment: If you intend to turn the triac on with the optocoupler, the latter should be connected from MT2 to gate on each triac. This is a very dangerous circuit, if both the triacs find themselves turned on a lot of current could flow.